# How to remove the copyright box on a paper that uses the ACM sig-alternate.cls class file?

Tags: titles, copyright, acm

The ACM provides a LaTeX template called sig-alternate.cls ([webpage](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates), [class file](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls)). The current version is 2.4 released in April, 2009.

I would like to submit a paper for review using this class file. Unfortunately, the class file reserves some space at the bottom of the first page in the first column for a copyright notice. This copyright notice is required for the camera ready version of the paper, but not for the initial paper submission. How can I remove this copyright notice and reclaim this space?

Comment: A non-answer, for the sake of completeness: The standard way to remove the copyright notice is to use the `\toappearbox{...}` command. This allows you to *replace* the copyright notice with a boxed text. This does not save any space, but usually this is a *good* feature: you can have identical layouts in the camera-ready version and in your own version.

Comment: Hmm, when I add \toappearbox{something} that does not change anything... What am I missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and its `\patchcmd` macro to selectively change `sig-alternate`' s definition of `\maketitle`, i.e. remove the `\@copyrightspace` macro (which is responsible for the copyright space).

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@copyrightspace}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{lockstep}
\title{How to remove the copyright space}
\maketitle

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

(The [`blindtext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

Comment: This does not work for me.

Answer (score 46):

In the newest format (e.g. ACM MM 2020), you can set nonacm and authorversion in the documentclass:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,authorversion,nonacm]{acmart}
```

See also the official guide: https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf. (April 2020).

Comment: That should be the accepted answer! :)

Comment: should be pushed higher

Comment: this works for me while other answers did not work, thanks!

Answer (score 45):

The accepted answer somehow doesn't work for me, but I found another solution [here](http://ryanlei.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/latex-remove-the-copyright-space-from-the-acms-sig-alternate-template/).

Simply add the following lines before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@copyrightspace{\relax}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: worked for me under overleaf

Answer (score 28):

I fixed the problem by writing \setcopyright{none} before \begin{document} at the top. FYI I was using overleaf.

Comment: I tried all the of the above and only this one worked. I am using Sharelatex.com.

Comment: didn't completely remove it on the ACM 2020 template

Comment: The command removed the copyright statement. Still the conference, ISBN, doi remains. By the way, I was using texmaker/texlive.

Comment: Same for me. This removes the copyright statement but the conference, ISBN, doi remains.

Comment: Look to @Jasper Uijlings's answer for removal of conference, ISBN, doi

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation in the [template source code](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/article-templates/sig-alternate-05-2015.cls):

- If you use the [preprint] option, the copyright text is removed but the space is preserved.

  ```
  % ACM SIG template
  \documentclass[preprint]{sig-alternate}
  ```
- If you use the [preprint] option of the template, you can use `\toappear` and `\toappearbox` to replace the copyright text. You must define the text to appear before issuing `\maketitle`. For instance

  ```
  % ACM SIG template
  \documentclass[preprint]{sig-alternate}
  % text to appear
  \toappear{To appear in the most incredible conference}
     % other commands
  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
     % other commands
  \end{document}
  ```
- If you want to remove completely the copyright space, you can redefine a `@copyrightspace` variable used to create the box at the bottom. You must redefine it before the `\maketitle`

  ```
  %% remove the box 
  \makeatletter
  \def\@copyrightspace{\relax}
  \makeatother
  ```
- If you want a smaller box, you can redefine the `@copyrightspace` variable too. Originally, the height of the box is 1". You can define a different size. For instance, the following code produce a smaller box. Note the `\setlength` with `0.2pc` instead of `1pc`

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \def\@copyrightspace{
      \@float{copyrightbox}[b]
      \begin{center}
          \setlength{\unitlength}{0.2pc}
              \begin{picture}(100,6) %Space for copyright notice
                  \put(0,-0.95){\crnotice{\@toappear}}
              \end{picture}
          \end{center}
      \end@float}
  \makeatother
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the answer here: [How to remove conference information from the ACM 2017 SIGCONF template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346292/how-to-remove-conference-information-from-the-acm-2017-sigconf-template/346309).

```
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference information in first column
\pagestyle{plain} % removes running headers
```

Use the preprint format will also remove the two-column layout, which I want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

The following will replace the copyright text with blank or whatever you prefer. However, this will not reclaim the space, but you might need that for the camera ready version anyway.

Add the following **before** the `\begin{document}`

- For a text or blank **with a rectangle** around:
  `\toappearbox{My-text-or-blank}`
- For a text or blank with **no
  rectangle**: `\toappear{My-text-or-blank}`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking to change the footer ACM text just put the following code before the document beginning and good luck.

```
\makeatletter
\def\runningfoot{\def\@runningfoot{}}
\def\firstfoot{\def\@firstfoot{}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

### Change ACM default Format:

You can use the following commands to remove copyright, reference format and footer/header of ACM default format:

```
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\setcopyright{none}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}
\pagestyle{plain}

\setcopyright{none}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@formatdoi[1]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found a file in Overleaf template named Settings.tex and I removed the part concerning copyright.