# A compact LaTeX template for sig conferences that does not produce a permission block

Tags: titles, templates, copyright

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the copyright box on a paper that uses the ACM sig-alternate.cls class file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21536/how-to-remove-the-copyright-box-on-a-paper-that-uses-the-acm-sig-alternate-cls-c)

I am editing a paper with LaTeX and I use the template `sig-alternate.cls`, which is compact. But this template will produce the permission block. By what means can I remove the block while keep the paper compact?

Comment: If you're referring to the copyright notice, the following should solve your problem: [How to remove the copyright box on a paper that uses the ACM `sig-alternate.cls` class file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21536/5764) Give some feedback regarding the being a possible duplicate question.

Comment: problem solved based on the posts above, thanks!