# How to remove conference information from the ACM 2017 SIGCONF template?

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, acm, doi

I have downloaded the new ACM template for conference proceedings (sigconf format). Even when I comment out the lines that are related to conference information, price, DOI, etc. I get the following lines on the first page:

```
Conference’17, Washington, DC, USA
2016. 978-x-xxxx-xxxx-x/YY/MM. . . $15.00
DOI: 10.1145/nnnnnnn.nnnnnnn
```

I have uncommented the line

```
\setcopyright{none}
```

so the copyright notice is gone, but the above information is still there (from acmart.cls)

Additionally, I get the paper's name on odd pages and conference information at the top of every page. How should I remove these lines?

Comment: Try the `nonacm` option. <https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/consolidated-tex-template/acmart.pdf>

Comment: Second the `nonacm` option, which uses the same typesetting but without the header, footer and the permission block. As stated in the documentation "Use the class typeseing options for a non-ACM document, which will not include the conference/journal header and footers or permission statements".

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Add the following lines below the `\documentclass` line.

```
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference information in first column
\pagestyle{plain} % removes running headers
```

**Removing "Manuscript submitted to ACM":** add `\fancyfoot{}` in the preamble and `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\maketitle`

**Removing DOI information only:** Using the command `\acmDOI{}` to set the DOI to an empty string has only a limited effect: In the *ACM reference format* and in the copyright notice the prefix `https://doi.org/` still remains. Only when using the class option `authorversion`, this prefix will vanish in the footnote, but will still be part of the ACM reference. (Imho this is a bug.) Here is a hack to get rid of this prefix (and of any DOI that has been set).

Add the lines

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@formatdoi[1]{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

after the `\documentclass` line. This will remove the DOI line in the *ACM reference format* completely (including the line break). The conference information in the footnote will still retain the line break, which leads to a small extra vertical space. To avoid this, suppress the complete copyright notice by `\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}` (see above), or 
redefine `\footnotetextcopyrightpermission` in a more sophisticated way by just removing the `\@formatdoi` command with the preceding `\\` from the original definition (see the class file).

Comment: Do you now how to remove just the doi line?

Comment: @Derzu See my updated answer.

Comment: FWIW: bugs can be reported to https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart and the author is usually very responsive (especially for things that don't affect camera-ready output, hence don't need ACM approval).
For this issue there's a recent pull request with changes to the class file: https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/pull/185

Comment: Unfortunately, I added the first line after documentclass and all the information still appears, but only on the first page.

Comment: @6005 I've just tested the commands with the recent version of `sample-sigconf.tex`, and the lines have exactly the effect as specified in the comments. The first line, `\settopmatter{printacmref=false}` removes the citation information that appears below the abstract, as expected. Clearly, this information is on the first page (or on the second, at the latest). What else do you expect?

Comment: @6005 Please provide a small complete document that shows your problem. Otherwise it is hard to guess what's going wrong.

Comment: @gernot Thanks. It's OK, I think the template I'm using may be different. I've decided to use the default settings, but if I decide I want to change, I'll ask a new Q and link to this one.

Comment: Unfortunately, `authorversion` now adds a note "This is the author’s version of the work. It is posted here for your personal use. Not for redistribution. The definitive Version of Record was published in (…)".