# Remove ACMReference from Sigconf December 2016 latex template

Tags: cross-referencing, acm, paper

I want to remove the ACMReference after the abstract. This fix is not working for me \settopmatter{printacmref=false}. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, which specific template are you referring to, canyou give us a link?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346292/remove-conference-information-from-acm-2017-sigconf-template/346309#346309

Comment: Oh apparently I had to put it AFTER \begin{document}!

Answer (score 1):

Putting it right after the documentclass worked for me. I don't think you need to do it after \begin{document}. Perhaps the problem is that you put it after \abstract? I think the macro is called during the creation of the abstract.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
```