# ACMart documentclass creates a vertical space at the end of the second column of the first page

Tags: spacing, debugging, acmart

When using `\documentclass[sigconf,letter]{acmart}` I noticed that without regard for the text (I tried different nudges), latex always leaves a space of a couple line-spaces on the end of the right column. I deactivated some directives according to [How to remove conference information from the ACM 2017 SIGCONF template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346309/1498). The space varies depending on the sentence structure above, but it never goes away.

[image: screenshot]

Where could that come from and how do I troubleshoot this?