# How can I remove the running header from acm sigconf template?

Tags: acm, header

I use the acm sigconf template and found a problem: from the second page of my generated PDF, at the top of every page there is a header, with conference information, title or authors' names. (e.g. `Conference’17, July 2017, Washington, DC, USA` and `John and Jean` on left and right side of first row). I want to remove all these running headers starting from second page.

I found similar question asked here: [How to remove conference information from the ACM 2017 SIGCONF template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346292/how-to-remove-conference-information-from-the-acm-2017-sigconf-template)

However, I added the following code but they didn't work:

```
\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference information in first column
\pagestyle{plain} % removes running headers
```

I tried `\pagestyle{empty}` and it didn't work as well.

A minimal example to show the problem is given below. (There is a lot of text I copied from website, only to extend the example to second page, in order to show the running header.)

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\settopmatter{printacmref=false} % Removes citation information below abstract
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} % removes footnote with conference information in first column

\pagestyle{plain} % removes running headers

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables



% Copyright
\setcopyright{none}


\begin{document}
\title{This is the title}


\author{John}
\email{john@gmail.com}

\author{Jean}
\email{jean@gmail.com}


% The default list of authors is too long for headers.
%\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{B. Trovato et al.}


\begin{abstract}

This is the abstract
\end{abstract}


\keywords{kw1, kw2, kw3}


\maketitle

Special Notes for Catalina



MacTeX-2019 works fine on Catalina once it is installed. When Catalina was first released to developers, Apple said that install packages for Catalina must be notarized and software installed must adopt a hardened runtime. These conditions hold for BasicTeX-2019 and Ghostscript, but not for MacTeX-2019. However, the requirements have been turned off for most betas of Catalina and seem to be still off in the release version, so MacTeX-2019 should install without trouble.

In one beta version of Catalina, perhaps beta 5, the restriction was turned on and the MacTeX-2019 install package refused to install. An experimental notarized version of MacTeX-2019 installed fine during that beta period and is available at http://tug.org/~koch/MacTeX-2019.pkg. It will replace the old MacTeX-2019 install package as soon as Apple reinstates the notarization restriction.



Installing MacTeX



After downloading, move the file MacTeX.pkg to the desktop or another convenient spot, and double click it to install. Follow the straightforward instructions. Installation on a recent Macintosh takes about ten minutes.

At the end of installation, the installer will report "Success." But sometimes, the installer puts up a dialog saying "Verifying..." and then the install hangs. In all cases known to us, rebooting the Macintosh fixes this problem. After the reboot, install again.

If other problems are reported during installation, skip to the section "Installation Errors" below.

MacTeX writes a symbolic link /Library/TeX/texbin which indirectly points to the TeX Live binary directory. Configure your GUI programs to use this link. The GUI programs we supply should automatically configure themselves. On older systems, you may have seen the link /usr/texbin which did the same thing. When Apple produced El Capitan, they modified the system so users could no longer write directly to the /usr directory and this rule remains in effect today. Therefore we replaced /usr/texbin with /Library/TeX/texbin.

MacTeX does not overwrite the TeX Distribution from the previous year. Users who run into trouble can switch to the previous distribution until the new distribution is fixed. Long ago we installed a Preference Pane which could do this switching, but this functionality is now in TeX Live Utility, which is in /Applications/TeX. To switch, use the Configure menu item "Select Default TeX Live Version."

MacTeX completely configures TeX, so after installation it is ready to use. Go to "/Applications/TeX/Docs and Spell Utilities/READ ME FIRST.pdf" and read this short document to get started. The document leads a new user through the complete process of writing and typesetting a short LaTeX document. The location "/Applications/TeX/Docs and Spell Utilities/Documents" also contains "What is installed", which lists all the components of MacTeX and their installation locations.

MacTeX installs TeX Live, which contains TeX, LaTeX, AMS-TeX, and virtually every TeX-related style file and font. TeX Live is maintained by TeX User Groups across the world. TeX Live is compiled from the same sources for all platforms: Macintosh, Windows, Linux, Unix.

MacTeX also installs Ghostscript, an open source version of Postscript, and it installs the GUI programs TeXShop, LaTeXiT, TeX Live Utility, and BibDesk. In "/Applications/TeX/Docs and Spell Utilities/Spelling" it contains an install package for cocoAspell, a spelling service which does not mark LaTeX commands as misspelled.


Updating from an Earlier MacTeX Installation


If you previously installed MacTeX, you may already have your own favorite front ends and GUI programs. Perhaps, in addition, you have Ghostscript from another source such as MacPorts or HomeBrew. In these cases, it is easy to install just the pieces you need. Download MacTeX using the earlier link. Double click to install. Several pages of information will be displayed; one of the last is shown below. Click the "Customize" button to obtain a page allowing you to select one or more of "TeX Live", "Ghostscript", "GUI Applications."

Customize


It is not necessary to remove the earlier TeX Live installation before installing a new one, and indeed we don't recommend that because MacTeX makes it easy to revert to the older version if the new version has a flaw. If you really need the extra space, other sections of these web pages explain how to remove older versions of MacTeX.


Installation Errors


Sometimes at the end of installation, the installer will report "The installation failed The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance."
In almost all cases, this error is caused by a faulty download. There is an easy way to check this. Go to /Applications/Utilities and run Terminal. Type

md5
and a space. Then drag the install package icon "MacTeX.pkg" and drop it on the Terminal window. Push RETURN. Terminal will print a message and then a long item with letters and numbers. Compare this number to the md5 sum at the top of this page just under the MacTeX.pkg link. If the two numbers are different, your download was defective and you must download again. If you downloaded with a third party browser, we recommend trying Safari for the new download.
If you are having trouble downloading MacTeX, note that the download link points to a "multiplexer" site which parcels out requests to various up-to-date CTAN mirrors. Occasionally users have trouble getting the package from this multiplexer. In that case, choose a specific mirror on this mirror page.

MacTeX is a very large package. If your network is noisy, you might want to try downloading and installing BasicTeX. See Smaller Download. BasicTeX is very much smaller, and yet has most files, fonts, and programs to process TeX, so this is a rapid way to get a working TeX. BasicTeX need not be uninstalled before installing MacTeX, so once you convince yourself that our packages work, you can return to the main task of installing MacTeX. TUG strongly recommends the full MacTeX for most users, including beginners,

So far, we've given alternatives for bad downloads. But if your download has the correct md5 sum, and you still get a message that installation failed, it is time to click "MacTeX Installer Support" at the bottom of this page and ask for help.

Updating Various Pieces After Installation


TeX Live 2019 and the various GUI programs installed by MacTeX are up to date as of April, 2019. But various pieces may have been updated since then. Each of our GUI programs has a menu item called "Check for Updates." Select this item to update the program to the current version. The TeX Live command line files are updated daily. To install these updates, use TeX Live Utility in /Applications/TeX.
The program xdvi requires at least XQuartz 2.7.9. If you use this program, update XQuartz to the latest version at http://www.xquartz.org.

TeX Live DVD


Free copies of TeX Live are available over the internet, but this can be problematic if your internet connection is unstable. Members of the TeX User Group (TUG) receive a free DVD containing the full TeX Live for all common platforms. TUG also sells this DVD to others. For details, click on the TUG icon at top right.




\end{document}
```

How can I solve this problem? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I run your example code it works correctly (i.e., the header is not shown on the second page, and when I remove `\pagestyle{plain}` then the header is shown). Are you sure that you check the right file, and not some old pdf that remains from a previous run? Alternatively it could be a version issue, i.e., your version of `acmart.cls` or one of the packages could be too old or too new and something could have changed in the way the headers work - which versions do you use (put `\listfiles` at the start of the code and check the log)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I can confirm that I'm looking at the latest pdf. For the acmart.cls, how do I check the version? I use Texstudio to compile, build and view the PDF. When I add `\listfiles` and run, the log looks like as follows: `Overfull \hbox (9.66054pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (3.77432pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
Overfull \vbox (2.124pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []`.

Comment: With 'log' I mean the log file, not the log of TeXstudio. The log file is a file that is created in the same folder as your `.tex` file, with the same name but the extension `.log` (so if your document is called `mydocument.tex` then the log file is called `mydocument.log`. You can open this file with a text editor such as Notepad. This is a very long file (more than 1000 lines for your minimal example) and with `\listfiles` there is a list, probably near the end of the file, that shows the class and all packages with version information.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. I was able to find the test.log and the version: 
`Document Class: acmart 2019/03/29 v1.59 Typesetting articles for the Associatio
n for Computing Machinery`. How can I use the proper version?

Answer (score 15):

The above solutions didn't work for me.

What did work was adding

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

immediately after

```
\maketitle
```

Comment: Well, this didn't work to get rid of the pointless, annoying, and horrible header on the Springer Nature template

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer on 2023, which write after I try all these solutions and finally figure out a way to completely clean the running headers while preserve line numbers:
First, add `nonacm` to remove the conference running headers.

```
\documentclass[nonacm,sigplan,review]{acmart}
```

Then, add `[]` in `\title` command:

```
\title[]{Your Title}
```

The text in `[]` is the short title for running headers. If you set it as empty, it will show an empty running headers. So you clean up all the running headers!

It really saves me after getting 'text height exceed' violation warnings from paper submission websites ：-）

`\pagestyle{plain}` also removes the running headers but also removes line numbers, which is not expected in my case.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because a) it is more idiomatic and b) it does not involve the side effects (missing line numbers) of the older answer.